# open a file in a specific tab in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was curious about one thing, though I'm almost sure it's not posible :)
When you open a specific type of file in Xcode it should open in a specific tab.

Example.
I have a tab called interface.
When I open(click) a `xib` file to reveal inside that tab (interface).

Thank you,

Comment: well, it a point of view :)

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the file, it will open in a new tab.

Comment: if i have 5 tabs predefined with specific behaviour and a layout, i need to open that specific file in that specific tab. It;s posible i'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

On xcode :
Behaivors -> Edit Behaivors -> General tab
Click Activation 
Navigation : Uses Primary Editor
Optional Navigation : Uses Seperate Tab
Double Click Navigation : Uses Seperate Tab

After you can open files on new tab when you push option + click.

Comment: well, that not what i want, read the question again and keep in mind i want xib files to show up in a tab called 'interface' even if now i'm on a tab called 'edit'. 'interface' tab is already open and configure for editing xib files.